# Graphing Algorithm for many nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, sigma.js

I have been trying to develop a web based application to help in the graphing of nodes and their interactions.

I have attempted to use the Sigma.Js with the Force Atlas extension.

For my simple tests (few nodes) the results are quite good-looking, however with an additional thousand nodes the result becomes quite a mess.

[image: Many nodes vs Few Nodes]

Is there any such way to make the result more view able? (easier on the eyes/not just 1 big blob) How would I go about doing this? Are there any algorithms already written(that I may implement?)

Comment: Google search "graph clustering algorithms" or "hierarchical graph clustering".

Comment: You use SCC's to divide graph into smaller no of component(represent each SCC as single node which expands on selection)

Comment: SCC == Strongly connected component?

Comment: How are you generating these graphs? To get a graph to display well, you need to know something about it's structure - and there are certainly classes of graph that have no visually pleasing layout at all. To me, it looks like the big red blob on the RHS is one of those, with too high an expansion coefficient to be effectively teased apart.

Comment: Highly connected node graphs do not have a "sub manifold" that allows them to be viewed easily. Even if you space out the nodes a great distance, it will not make the blob any easier to understand. Perhaps you need another way of looking at your data. d3.js has a bunch of algorithms, include its own force graph layout. http://d3js.org/

Comment: @AndyJones I generate these graphs by parsing through an xml document. I am not in control on what is in those documents. The following up top are from random datasets I found online that match the xml format that I am to work with.

Comment: @brainwipe The following up top is a force directed algorithm(which I used because it used the same input that I was given). I can however parse through my data to match d3js's input and do it that way to see if it will give me better results.

Comment: @user2100799 Mind linking to a couple of those XML documents? If you can't, the best option I can think of is to look at what the [Open Graph Drawing Framework](http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php) uses. In particular, their layered algorithm might improve your results.

Comment: @AndyJones A sample one would be like the following: http://gexf.net/data/yeast.gexf (this is the blob shown above) or http://gexf.net/data/celegans.gexf

Comment: @user2100799 Was hoping it'd be domain-specific, which might have given some clues as to what particular algorithms might serve you well. Sorry, I got nothing :(. Best you can do is pick over various hierarchical/multi-scale force algorithms as JayC suggests, and see what works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Fruchterman-Reingold force layout (for which there is a [sigma plugin](https://gist.github.com/sheymann/5057611)). It specifically minimises the number of links that cross each other, so it is in general more suitable for large graphs (unless all the nodes have lots of connections).

In addition, the [fisheye plugin](http://sigmajs.org/examples/a_plugin_example_advanced.html) may help to make more sense of the graph after it has been drawn.

Answer (score 2):

[sigma.layout.forceAtlas2](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/linkurious-version/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2) scales much better, however it won't do miracles if the graph has a strong density of connections.